# Divide document into paragraphs

Tags: java, regex

I want to divide my document into paragraphs.

First I used TIKA to extract my text from (PDF, DOC) format.

After this I used `Split()` to divide the text into lines.

```
String[]lines=handler.toString().split("\n");\\handler from TIKA that extract the whole text from document
```

And then I used regex to extract specific information (e.g company name, designation, loyalty).

It works perfect until I have a paragraph that divided to many lines 
i.e:

> Worked in Lycatel B.O.S. (P) Ltd. India Office, Chennai as Telecom
>   Billing Analyst from 22nd October 07 to 3rd June 08.

It will divide to:

```
paragraph [1] :  Worked in Lycatel B.O.S. (P) Ltd. India Office, Chennai as Telecom
paragraph [2] : Billing Analyst from 22nd October 07 to 3rd June 08.
```

Since I apply `Matcher` for each paragraph:

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(paragraphs[i]);
```

The extracted data will be wrong because the 2 lines should be in the same paragraph.

I tried to split the text depending on `.`:

```
String[]lines=handler.toString().split(".");
```

However, companies that contain `.` in their names will be spit as well. For example:

> Lycatel B.O.S. (P) Ltd.

How could I divide my text so that the paragraph `[i]` will be until the full-stop (`.`)?

Comment: Is a paragraph, in your text, always concluded by a `.`?

Comment: yes, it is always concluded by (.)

Comment: Then split by `split(".\n")`

Comment: it's work fine for some cases but how about paragraphs that do not end after \n but after \t i.e. (**paragraph 1. paragraph2. \n paragraph3) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `(?sm)^.*?\\.$` but I doubt you can get perfect solutions to your problem with regex.

`(?s)` is the dotall flag, it will make `.` match line feeds.
`(?m)` is the multiline flag, so `$` will match the end of line (rather than only the end of string).
So with this regexp, we match as many characters (linefeeds included) as needed before we can match a `.` that is at the end of its line.

You can try it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gN4sM0/1).

Comment: thanx for the answer :)